# PHP Implement a trait, override and then calling it's parent trait

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel 5.3.. 
Model.php has the following function:

```
public function forceDelete()
{
    return $this->delete();
}
```

But, I'm implementing it with the softDeletes trait, which has the following function:

```
public function forceDelete()
{
    $this->forceDeleting = true;

    $deleted = $this->delete();

    $this->forceDeleting = false;

    return $deleted;
}
```

But, I'm overriding the function, with this:

```
public function forceDelete()
{
    echo "deleting";
    return parent::forceDelete();
}
```

On this last override, on the line where I call parent::forceDelete(), it calls the version from model.php and not from softDeletes.php. How could I make it call from softDeletes instead? Is it even possible?

Comment: Where is the parent class?

Comment: Well, the top parent is in model.php, the trait then implements from softDeletes.php, and I override in a class that extends model.php but implements softDeletes.php. When I call parent::forceDelete(), it calls from model.php, I want to call from softDeletes.php

Comment: The easy solution is just name it something else.  Personally I am not a fan of traits.  To me it's generally a sign of bad design.  I tried using them but I never find a valid reason that I actually need them.  I suppose if Laravel forces you to use them then ....  I would say from an atomic perspective its bad to call `$this` inside a triat on another method outside the trait as you have no guarantee it actually exists.

Comment: It's a Laravel design, I could rename it but I don't want o break design.. it will set updates up for errors

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best option is to name the trait method inside the class's `use` statement like this:

```
class SomeClass extends Model
{
    use SomeTrait {
       forceDelete as traitForceDelete;
    }

    public function forceDelete()
    {
        return $this->traitForceDelete();
    }
}
```